# Make whole css grid netsted div clickable with anchor tag centered

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to center anchor tags (Link 1, Link 2, Link 3, Link 4) in a CSS grid nested div. I also want the links to have padding around them, but it seems I have missed something. Have managed so far as below. Also, how can I achieve flexible row height for the graph 1 and graph 2 boxes without mentioning the height in the `grid-template-rows`?

[image]

I am trying to achieve something like this image:

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

main {
  width: 98 %;
  margin: 5 px 5 px;
  border: 1 px solid grey;
  display: grid;
  color: white;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 40px 300px 300px 60px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.div-header {
  background-color: #ff4757;
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.page-navbar {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10 px;
  background-color: #EEF5FB;
  color: #000;
}

.div-box1 {
  color: #000;
  border-right: 1px solid skyblue;
}

.div-link {
  text-align: center;
}

.page-navbar a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.div-box2 {
  border-right: 1px solid skyblue;
}

.div-box3 {
  border-right: 1px solid skyblue;
}

.div-box4 {}

.div-main-1 {
  color: #000;
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.div-main-2 {
  color: #000;
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.div-footer {
  background-color: steelblue;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: steelblue;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-links {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="div-header">
    <nav>
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="water_drop_black_24dp.svg" alt="logo" />
      </a>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="page-navbar">
    <div class="div-box1">
      <a href="#" class="div-link">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="div-box2">
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="div-box3">
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="div-box4">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-main-1">Chart 1</div>
  <div class="div-main-2">Chart 2</div>
  <div class="div-footer">Footer</div>
</main>
```

Comment: It is really good that you use semantic tags such as `<main>` and `<nav>`. Unfortunately you stopped right there. The nav should semantically not be part of the `<main>` but of the `<header>`. WHy use `<div class="header">` instead of using the semantic tag there as well? The semantic tag for lists of links is `<menu>` which behaves the same as an `<ul>`

Comment: Which boxes are "graph 1" and "graph 2"? If you're trying to make a layout that looks like the second image, which links/text is supposed to be "Total," "analytics," "devices," "alarms," and "settings"?

Comment: @DavidThomas, Thanks. What I want is the LInk 1, Link 2, Link 3 and Link 4 (anchor tags - 1st image) to look like Total, Analytics, Devices, Alarm in the 2nd image.

Comment: Sorry, used a different image to upload. The Graph1 and Graph2 are below the Link 1...Link 4 section. Since I am still trying my hands on a dashboard layout, I had to use grid-template-rows to give fixed heights to each section, including Graph1 and Graph2. Is this correct way of doing it or can I use auto or 1fr?

Comment: @tacoshy, thanks for pointing out the semantics. I will try to design a css grid dashboard layout with the same.